# Making a simple form in yii which has 2 input fields and a textarea

Tags: yii

I am a *yiibie*. I want to make a simple form in yii which has a name, dob fields and a text area for address. Can anyone please help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a skeleton Yii application  `YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive` and look at contact.php. See [Getting started with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your form model, you are returning an object with these attributes to the view. Assuming the form is for a `User`...

```
class UserFormModel extends CFormModel
{
    public $name;
    public $dob;
    public $address;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ... add rules here ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, return this form model to the view

```
public function actionSomething()
{
    // ... some other code ...
    $uf = new UserFormModel();
    $this->render('view-file', array(
        'model' => $uf,
    ));
}
```

Then in your view, `view-file.php`...

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array()); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'dob'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'address'); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

... should get you a minimal form for your purpose.